# Mysql won't start on CentOS 6.7 running Plesk

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, database, plesk

I have a Plesk server, and yesterday I tried to update it to the newest version.

After a couple of tries, I couldn’t reach my Plesk panel anymore.
Getting this error:

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Abstract.php:144)
```

And all the database traffic is down. Looks like MySQL isn’t running right.

Yeah, mysql won't start.

Any suggestions to get it back running?

Comment: Yeah, they cant do anything for me, restarted the server many times now.

Comment: my log file, tells me this:
`Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306`